# Alfresco, specify request format using REST API

Tags: alfresco

I've seen Alfresco offers two kinds of login through it's REST APIs: a GET one and a POST one. In the POST method, it's required that the input is in JSon format. Is it possible to change it in xml format?

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to /alfresco/service/api/login. The POST webscript is implemented in Java by the org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.bean.LoginPost class. The class parses json so changing to xml is not a simple matter of configuration.

The best approach would be to leave this webscript alone and to implement another one that takes xml as input. For the implementation you can take inspiration from LoginPost, with the necessary modifications.